# How to enable gmusicbrowser's plugin Gnome mmkeys in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, gmusicbrowser

Gnome mmkeys is a plugin for gmusicbrowser which allows gmusicbrowser to respond to multimedia keys on the keyboard (play, pause, etc.). I tried to enable it via the Plugins tab in the Settings window of gmusic broser, but I get the following error:

> Can't find the dbus Settings Daemon for gnome or MATE

What package do I have to install to get this working?
What's the name of the "dbus Settings Daemon" package, so I can find it with `apt-get`?

Comment: relevant: http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.com/2011/11/use-multimedia-keys-with-gmusicbrowser.html, but I think there should be a less hackish solution. The multimedia keys work for controlling the volume. Why is it so problematic to control play/pause also?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have exact solution for your problem with gnome-mmkeys, but a little workaround since we only need a few keys, right?

You can set your keys directly, since Xubuntu knows them.
[image]

Comment: thanks for reformatting my reply. However this workaround didn't solve the problem, since those hotkeys work only when program is open. I switched to exaile, which supports command line attributes like -n -p -s -t. That can be set in global keyboard settings. But it doesn't solve the problem mentioned here.